# how call a azure function from a html?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I need the following. Create an azure function that generates qr code. Until then I found a tutorial. HttpTrigger, in javascript, with node -qrcode library

But I need to call this function in a simple html/css I made. how to make?

The azure function looks like this:

//require the module qrcode

```
const QRCode = require('qrcode');


module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
    

    if(req.query.text) { 
        let code;
        try {
            code = await QRCode.toDataURL(req.query.text);
        } catch (err) {
            context.log.error('ERROR', err);
            throw err;
        }
        if (code) {
            context.res = {
                body: code
                
                
            }
            
        } else {
            context.res = {
                body: "Error: QR Code rendering error",
                status: 400
            }
        }
    } else {
        context.res = {
            body: "Error: Missing query string text",
            status: 400
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you publish your function, you should get the Function URL from the Azure portal, and then make an HTTP call from inside your html page(for example using jQuery, ajax etc). In your function.json, you should have mentioned which HTTP methods your function supports , example GET, POST. Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-node